# Correlation in meta analysis

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am conducting a meta-analysis, and the main question is: "Is there a relationship between corrected angle and the functional outcome?"

I have some studies that report the corrected angle and functional outcome score without reporting the correlation. For each outcome, I have the mean, SD and sample size.

How can I calculate the correlation coefficient ($r$) for each study in order to pool them?

Comment: Is it possible to contact the original authors and ask them? This often provides a few more results.

Comment: Do you have mean , S. D. etc. for " coorrected angle" as well. ?  what are  the variables - define.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Calculate a Cohen's d for each study [(equations here)](https://www.meta-analysis.com/downloads/Meta-analysis%20Effect%20sizes%20based%20on%20means.pdf).
2. Convert this Cohen's d to a correlation coefficient $r$ [(equations here)](https://www.meta-analysis.com/downloads/Meta-analysis%20Converting%20among%20effect%20sizes.pdf).
3. You will then do the typical Fisher's z-to-r transformation, and the variance of these can be directly taken from the sample size N [(equations here).](https://www.meta-analysis.com/downloads/Meta-analysis%20Effect%20sizes%20based%20on%20correlations.pdf)

There are many, many R packages and calculators out there that will do these calculations for you. If you an R user, [here is a recent literature review of all the different meta-analysis packages out there.](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/1076998616674315?journalCode=jebb)

Comment: Careful: Converting d to r in the manner described in that chapter gets you a point-biserial correlation. Also, Fisher's r-to-z transformation is not a variance-stabilizing transformation for point-biserial correlations. I would suggest to convert the d values to biserial correlations and meta-analyze those. See also: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jrsm.1218/abstract

Comment: @Wolfgang +1 thanks for the heads up. Why do you not suggest using point-biserial? Is it because the transformation doesn't stabilize the variance? Once I convert using biserial, is it safe to use 1/(n-3) as the variance?

Comment: Fisher's variance stabilizing transformation is only applicable to Pearson product-moment correlations, not point-biserial or biserial correlations (or tetrachoric correlations). Whether we should analyze point-biserial or biserial correlations depends on whether we consider the dichotomous variable inherently dichotomous or a dichotomized version of a continuous variable.

Comment: Thanks! I was using `escalc("OR", ...)` to go to OR... then to d... then to r (per that book). Little did I know it was much easier with "RTET." But it also pumps out a variance (vi)... Can't I just use 1/(n-3) after I convert yi to Fisher's z?

Comment: Not for tetrachoric correlations.

Comment: So how would I get the right variances $vi$ for tetrachoric and biserial correlations $yi$ after I do the Fisher's r-to-z transformation on them? That is, I know how to to r-to-z for $yi$, but not their corresponding $vi$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60238/discussion-between-mark-white-and-wolfgang).

Comment: I do not think data is available for computing Cohen's d .

Comment: @subhashc.davar if you have means, SDs, and n, you can calculate Cohen's d

Comment: Apparently there is no control and expeimental grouplng.